# pushing a char into the stack does not work

Tags: c++, class, stack

I'm trying to make a stack of chars with linked list

so I made two classes for stack and node

**but when I'm trying to push a char into the stack:**

```
stack->push('x')
```

it does not work and give these two errors : expected an identifier , expected a type specifier

```
    class stack
    {
    private:
        node* top;
        int size;
    public:
        stack() { top = NULL; size = 0; }
        node* gettop() { return top; }
        int getsize() { return size; }
        void settop(node* t) { top = t; }
        void setsize(int s) { size = s; }
        bool isempty() { return getsize() == 0; }
        char gettopelement() { return top->getdata(); }
        void push(char x){   top = new node (x, top);
    size += 1; }

        char pop() {

if (isempty() == true)
        cout << "erorr stack is empty";

    else {

        node* p = top;
        char temp = gettopelement();
        top = top -> next;
        delete p;
        size -= 1;
        return temp;

    }
}

    };


class node
{
public:
    char data;
    node* next;
    node(char d) { data = d; next = NULL; }
    node(char d, node* n) { data = d; next = NULL; }
    int getdata() { return data; }
    node* getnext() { return next; }
    void setdata(char d) { data = d; }
    void setnext(node* n) { next = n; }
    
};
```

Comment: This code does not compile.  It does not reproduce the described problem.  A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: The code you show here [does not produce the results](https://godbolt.org/z/no7xfrxK6) that you claim it does.

Comment: The line `stack->push('x')` does not appear in your code. Please show code that demonstrates your specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'stack' is seemingly the name of your class. You need to instantiate it. Like

```
stack someStackInstance;
someStackInstance.push('x');
```

You might want to show your complete code where you have `stack->push('x')` (not you're using a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
stack someObj;
someObj.push(whatever_you-want_to_push);
```

`->` operator is used on pointers.

declare `class node` before `class stack`. my suggestion is to use `std::stack`.
improvements in your code:

```
node(char d) { data = d; next = NULL; }
node(char d, node* n) { data = d; next = NULL; }
```

can be written in better manner as:

```
node(char d, node* n = NULL) { data = d; next = NULL; }
```

actually, I don't see any use of the passed argument of `node *n`. you are not using it in current implementation.

Comment: Research initialization lists:  `node(char d, node * n = nullptr) : data(d), next(n) { ; }`